How to configure maven with fallback repository
My situation:
I basically need clientside implementation Artifactory virtual repos.
We are being forced to use GitLab (self-hosted) for package management for each project, and an entirely different package manager (nexus) for public artifacts. For all sorts of reasons outside this discussion, using a group repo in nexus is out of the question.
This means that I MUST configure maven client side to resolve packages with 2 different repositories: So, something like org.apache.* would resolve with maven central, and com.mycompany would resolve with the project specific repo. And I need/want to do this so it's super portable and simple, so it can build on a user machine or build in a CI/CD pipeline that is also in the process of moving from 1 GL instance to another.
The idea is that, when I type mvn install it will check maven central, see that GAV FOO:BAR:1.0.0 doesn't exist and fall back to the internal repo.
I know these artifacts are ok because in my testing I have mirrored to *, and created a virtual/group repo. I now know I can't do that for reasons, hence I need to configure this sort of behavior client side.
How can this be achieved?

Please [edit] your question what the problem is in adding multiple repositories to the pom.xml file.

Unless I'm not understanding the question properly, this is a basic functionality of maven. You can define a repositories element in a pom or your settings file and list as many repositorys in it as you want. Doing so in the pom would be more portable:
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

...
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>central</id>
        <url>https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2</url>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <id>jitpack</id>
        <url>https://jitpack.io</url>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <id>company-repo</id>
        <url>https://repo.company.com/maven2</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.example</groupId>
        <artifactId>example-library</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>


And this will resolve example-library from the company-repo?

Yeah, I thought this was part of it's basic functionality

Yes it will fall back to the third repository if the artifact isn't in the first two. IT goes in order.

You can configure the repositories in settings.xml file of Apache Maven

Create a new settings.xml file in your project root folder or you can also modify your global maven configuration by updating the settings.xml file in {ApacheMaven}/conf/settings.xml file

By default, Maven will look for the libraries in the order in which they are specified.

Giving below an example configuration for one internal repo with the backup repo as the maven public repo.


<settings xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0"
           xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
           xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.0.0.xsd">
  
    <repositories>
      <repository>
        <id>nexus</id>
        <name>Nexus Repository</name>
        <url>http://your-nexus-server/repository/maven-public/</url>
        <releases>
          <enabled>true</enabled>
        </releases>
        <snapshots>
          <enabled>true</enabled>
        </snapshots>
      </repository>
    </repositories>
  
    <mirrors>
      <mirror>
        <id>central</id>
        <mirrorOf>*</mirrorOf>
        <url>https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/</url>
      </mirror>
    </mirrors>
  
  </settings>


You create a settings.xml that contains all the relevant repositories. Maven then automatically checks them all in order.
Be careful, though, with the <mirror> definition. If you define a mirror of *, it will draw EVERY request.
